# Display SQL AVG function value on all rows

Tags: sql, average

My oracle table, "invoice" looks like this.

```
   INV_NUM   CUST_NUM INV_DATE             INV_AMOUNT
```

---

```
  8000       1000 23-Mar-08                235.89
  8001       1001 23-Mar-08                312.82
  8002       1001 30-Mar-08                 528.1
  8003       1000 12-Apr-08                194.78
  8004       1000 23-Apr-08                619.44
```

I need to write a select query that will diplay the inv_num,inv_amount and the average inv_amount. The expected output is like this.

```
   INV_NUM   INV_AMOUNT       AVG(INV_AMOUNT)
```

---

```
  8000       235.89               378.206
  8001       312.82               378.206
  8002       528.1                378.206
  8003       194.78               378.206
  8004       619.44               378.206
```

I want the value from the AVG function to be repeated in every row. I understand that the AVG function returns only a single row. I get an error when I try this query.

```
select inv_num,inv_amount,avg(inv_amount) from invoice;

ERROR at line 1: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Is there a way to get the avg value to be displayed in every row? I need some help figuring this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the analytic function:

```
select inv_num, inv_amount, avg(inv_amount) over () as avg_inv_amount
from invoice;
```

The analytic functions are a class of functions that are a lot like the aggregation functions.  However, instead of reducing the number of rows, the value is placed on each row of the original data.  In this case, the parentheses are empty.  They can also (in this case) take a `partition by` clause.  For instance, the following would give the average for each customer:

```
select inv_num, inv_amount, avg(inv_amount) over (partition by cust_num) as avg_inv_amount
from invoice;
```